# Wordpress - Increase amount of posts to be shown within specific category

Tags: php, wordpress

I've been running in to a problem.
I'm editing a custom wordpress theme. I want to make some adjusments to the FAQ page (created with custom post type).

Right now every subject of question (= also category) is showing only 5 answers (these are posts).
I wanted to know, how I could increate this number, so instead of 5, show 10 or rather, show all answers per subject.

This is the code:
archive-faq.php

```
                    <?php $terms = get_terms( 'faq_category' ); ?>
                <?php foreach( $terms as $term ): 
                    $args = array (
                        'post_type'              => 'faq',
                        'tax_query' => array(
                            array(
                                'taxonomy' => 'faq_category',
                                'field'    => 'id',
                                'terms'    => $term->term_id,
                            ),
                        ),
                    );

                    $query = new WP_Query( $args ); ?>

                    <h1><?php echo $term->name; ?></h1>

                     <?php while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post(); ?>

                        <div class="toggle-holder">
                            <h5 class="toggle"><span><?php the_title(); ?></span></h5>
                            <div class="toggle-box">
                                <div>
                                    <?php the_content(); ?>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                    <?php endwhile; ?>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
                <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

An important part is:

```
                                <div class="toggle-box">
                                <div>
                                    <?php the_content(); ?>
                                </div>
                            </div>
```

Where the_content() , is showing the posts that are in a certain category.
However it's nowhere to be found why , the page is only showing up to 5 posts (answers) and not any more ?

Things I've tried:

```
$query = new WP_Query( $args );  
                    $query_posts('post_per_page=3'); ?>
```

Also:
putting `'showposts' => 8` under `'terms'    => $term->term_id,`

And I also tried:

```
                $query = new WP_Query( $args );  ?>

                        <?PHP
                                                query_posts( array(
'workcap' => $all_post_terms,
'showposts' => 8,
'caller_get_posts' => 1,
'post__not_in' => $do_not_duplicate ) ); ?>
```

->> In summary:
Why does the page only show up to 5 posts ?
And how do I change this property ?

PS. If you want to see the page: http://goo.gl/UnWRTz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The argument is `posts_per_page` and not `post_per_page`. Its a typo?

Try this:

```
$args = array (
    'post_type' => 'faq',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    //for now try without this taxonomy, if it works try with it.
    /*'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'faq_category',
            'field'    => 'id',
            'terms'    => $term->term_id,
        ),
    ),*/
);
```

Btw, you can find more info here: https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query

Comment: Indeed a typo. The issue has been resolved.
Thank you so much.